# "the instructor blew his whistle and off ran the runners."

Tags: sentence-usage

> 1. The instructor blew his whistle and **off ran the runners**.

Why not:

> 2. The instructor blew his whistle and **the runners ran off**.

Comment: The speaker might also be trying to avoid confusion with the common phrase "to run off" meaning to escape.  Although the meaning is clear through context, a native speaker might be amused to imagine that the runners abandoned the track and scattered, and this could distract the reader.

Answer (score 1):

**run off** is a phrasal verb like **run away**. The first part is a verb: the second is an adverb. It is possible to add emphasis to the adverb by inverting the word order- moving the adverb to the front. Sports commentators regularly say things like "...and off they go!" at the start of a race.

Another example is when somebody won't let go of a subject: you say

> there you go again!

It is also used frequently when talking to small children: "up you get" and possibly "ups-a-daisy".

Note that the phrasal verb **run off** can have both a literal meaning and an idiomatic meaning, defined in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/run_away) as **Escape from a place, person, or situation**. The second (non-inverted) version **the runners ran off** conveys the idiomatic version much more strongly than the first (inverted) version **off ran the runners**. Having said that, the inverted form is used in the title Pearl Jam's song [off he goes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_He_Goes) which is about somebody who finds life stressful and keeps running away.

Comment: Actually, the OP's second version is *exactly* like "run away" - it's a rather humorous sense that doesn't match the tone of the OP's first version. See: [*run off 1. to flee. The children rang our doorbell and then ran off. They ran off as fast as they could.*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+off)

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but the second sentences conveys two meanings.

1. **The instructor blew his whistle and off ran the runners.** - Here the word **[off]** is used like the word **[away]** and in sports it mainly means **[to start a race]**.

   - *The instructor blew his whistle and the runners started the race.*
2. **The instructor blew his whistle and the runners ran off.** - Can confuse some readers because it conveys two different meanings.

   - **to run off** as *away from the place in question; to or at a distance.*  (Adverb). *To leave somewhere or someone suddenly*. (Phrasal verb)
   - **to run off** as *start a journey or race; leave.* (Adverb)

> In British English there is an informal noun **[off]** which means *the start of a race, journey, or experience.*